# Same Raspberry, same configurations and and same pythoncode but diferent results

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I have two raspberrys p4 4gb ram ( same model ).

I instaled rasp os in a sd 32gb and in there it was instaled opencv dlib and other things to run a object detection.

after that i cloned my sd to other raspberry.

im my first sd it running in 3 fps and in my cloned sd its running 6fps.

i checked it twice its every thing tha same code and installed packages.

any one can help me to identify what causes this slowness?

im running a pyimagesearch object tracking code.

Comment: swap the two raspberrys ... unplug all the cables and the SD cards and swap the raspberrys only ... if the behavior does not follow the raspberrys, then swap the SD cards next

Comment: i tryed it. one raspberry is slower than other . i swaped sds

Comment: the slowness keeps in the same raspberry

Comment: Are they in identical cases? With identical cooling? Is it possible that you are throttling or overclocking? You don't mention cameras, but are they identical, Are the images the same size? Are you taking identical images? Are the power supplies identical (including the cable)?

Comment: yes identical cooling and same camera ( intelbras ip camera ) no throttling  or over. i got the SD from one raspberry and tested into another.

Comment: im using the same power suply. only changed the raspberry. one is fast other is slow.

Comment: You have provided no evidence to support your assertions. Neither have you explained what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Identification of the [root cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause) for this anomaly may be limited to those who have access to two things:

1. Chip-level and gate-level hardware documentation
2. Firmware documentation & access to the firmware sources

I won't say it's ***impossible*** for *clever people* to discover the *root cause* of this anomaly with the `vcgencmd` tools provided, but I will say that they are at considerable disadvantage to those with access - i.e. those with access to the closed sources.

While you couldn't classify it as the *root cause* of the anomaly you've seen (if it is in fact an anomaly), it strikes me as very likely that the RPi's closed-loop thermal management system is at the end of the causal chain. The **closed-loop thermal management system** takes various (?) temperature readings from the system, and ultimately (through firmware codes) adjusts the CPU's clock frequency. In other words, as the chip(s) heat up, the clock frequency goes down.

At the end of the day, we must recognize that the RPi is not an "open system", and there are some things we can't know about it. There are some things that we can try, but our efforts should be recognized for what they are: Not absolute answers, but a chance to [*"pull back the curtain"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubIpoPjBUds).

You might begin by calling on the `vcgencmd get_throttled` command. There is [some "official" documentation here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md), and there are [some "how-to" articles](https://newscrewdriver.com/2018/09/06/detecting-raspberry-pi-thermal-throttling-from-console/) that may provide additional insight. You could write a small script & run it periodically under `cron` or `systemd` on both systems & compare the results.

You might also peruse `/var/log/messages` for messages re throttling. This has the advantage of not placing any *additional* load on the system which could influence the results. I don't know that there is any documentation available to "decipher" these messages... I've always imagined `/var/log/messages` rather like the [*digital rain* screens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_digital_rain) in "The Matrix" - rows of gibberish without documentation.

As a more physical experiment - to see if the RPi's closed-loop thermal management system could be *isolated* as a variable in the causal chain - you could chill & fan the RPi's such that there was no throttling at all - at least none reported. Then run your test as you've outlined in your question.

We'll look forward to learning of your results :)